# Is there an adjectival form of "commodity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality, adjectives

The adjective would apply to the word dependence. I'd like to say commodital, but Google says it isn't a word.

Comment: Why is it that you think you need an adjective? Do you need to inflect it into the superlative degree or something? If you just need something that modifies a noun, you do not necessarily an adjective need.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use "commodity" itself as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct): "commodity dependence".  Or just rephrase with a preposition: "dependence on commodities".

**Edit:**  I did find one use of "commodital" in a pseudo-academic context ([link](http://wings.buffalo.edu/epc/authors/perloff/after_langpo.html)):

> Language-centered writing involves a major alteration in textual roles: of the socially defined functions of writer and reader as the productive and consumptive poles respectively of a commodital axis.

Comment: There's also the adjectives *commodious* (rare) and *commoditous* (even rarer), but they apply to *commodity* in the sense *something desired or convenient*, so I agree that *commodity* as an adjuct is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it is difficult to say what you are after exactly. But in a financial context the word you are after might be [*commoditized*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commoditization) or *commoditised* in British English.

An asset which is commoditised becomes indifferentiable in terms of its value. Examples of *commoditised goods* are gold and crude oil.